# Convert MongoCollection<Document> to DBCollection SpingBoot 1.5.4 to 2.1.0.RELEASE

Tags: java, database, mongodb, spring-boot

I have upgraded my springBoot version from `1.5.4` to `2.1.0.RELEASE`. I have the following piece of code which is creating trouble.

```
MongoCollection<Document> collection1 = mongoTemplate.getCollection(collection);

    MapReduceCommand cmd = new MapReduceCommand(collection1, map, reduce, "sd", MapReduceCommand.OutputType.INLINE,
            null);
    MapReduceOutput out = collection1.mapReduce(cmd);
```

Now `getCollection()` method returns MongoCollection and `MapReduceCommand` accepts DB collection. So is there any way to convert between the two ?

Comment: Then use the [`MongoCollection.mapReduce()`](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.9/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html#mapReduce-com.mongodb.client.ClientSession-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method like you were supposed to do when the code was written on the previous version of the driver as well. In all honestly for such old code you probably should look at converting the "mapReduce" operation to the aggregation framework as many newer added features should remove reliance on JavaScript for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

had similar issue when upgrading to spring-boot 2.0.4, worked with simple cast.
You can cast MongoCollection to DBCollection.

```
DBCollection dbCollection = (DBCollection) mongoTemplate.getCollection("someCollection");
```

This is not the best solution, but worked for me given there is not much context on this out there.

Comment: Okay Will give it a try. If that solves my problem I'll accept this.